# Installing evil-mode: ad-handle-definition 'evil-mode' got redefined

Tags: evil

I just installed `evil-mode` from melpa and when the installation finishes I get the message `ad-handle-definition: 'evil-mode' got redefined`.

[image: ad-handle-definition: 'evil-mode' got redefined]

I can then enable `evil-mode` but get the same warning. But the next time I open emacs and try to enable `evil-mode` I get this error: `Autoloading failed to define function evil-mode`

[image: Autoloading failed to define function evil-mode]

Searching around leads me to understand basically that somewhere along the line evil-mode gets redefined or lost, but I don't know where to start in debugging this.

I've tested:

1. Removing `evil` through the package manager and reinstalling
2. Removing the `evil-<date>` folder from the elpa packages and reinstalling
3. Installing the package from marmalade. I don't get the `ad-handle-definition` error then, but I still get `Autoloading failed to define function evil-mode`

I'm using emacs version 24.4.1 on OSX.

It kinda feels as if emacs is trying to tell me something behaving like this. ^^

Comment: This looks like it should be a bug report.  Submit [here](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues).

Comment: @tmalsburg ok, I've created [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/465/installing-from-marmalade-elpa-gives) there. Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem for a while now (Emacs 25.0.50.10, Ubuntu 14.04).  So thank you for reporting it.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, with version 20150408.1417, available in elp and melpa. The above ticket has been closed as "wontfix", but things are still broken.

Comment: `ad-handle-definition: 'evil-mode' got redefined` isn't an error. This happens when some *advice* for `evil-mode` has been evaluated in advance of `evil-mode` itself being defined or loaded. When the function is defined, the existing advice immediately redefines it, and Emacs provides notice that this has happened. If the advice is instead evaluated *afterwards*, this notice will not occur.

Answer (score 3):

To disable the initial warnings, I use:

```
(set 'ad-redefinition-action 'accept)
```

I haven't encountered your other errors, but they might be offshoots of the above. I haven't either investigated the side-effects of setting the above variable globally, I'll update this answer if I find any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a `(require 'evil)` in a function called by the hook `after-init-hook` fixes it for me:

```
(defun after-all-loads () (require 'evil))

(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'after-all-loads)
```

Comment: That didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few different files that I load in the init.el, one of these files loading the evil-mode related definitions. Adding the statements according to below in the evil-mode definition file solved the problem for me.

```
(require 'evil)
;; all the definitions goes here
(add-hook 'evil-after-load-hook (lambda () ...)) ; config
```